# Problema con radio button y javascript

Tags: javascript, html

les resumo un poco: Hice un pequeño chatbot en PHP, donde al momento de seleccionar un radio button, el valor se extraiga al input text y así enviar ese valor, pero hay un problema, cuando escribo cualquier cosa en el input text para ser enviado, el input text se reinicia y se queda en blanco, así que no me deja escribir otro valor, sólo los que están en los radio button. Traté de añadir una función con javascript para desmarcar los radio button y ver si me dejaba escribir cualquier valor pero no me dejó. Les dejo mi código y agradecería cualquier comentario o sugerencia, muchas gracias:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chatbot</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="title">ChatBot</div>
        <div class="form">
            <div class="bot-inbox inbox">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                </div>

                <div class="msg-header">

                    <p>Hola, somos una empresa. Por favor escribe lo que deseas conocer:

<form action="" method="post" target="_blank">
<br>
  <p>


    <label><input type="radio" name="tipos" value="Cotización" checked> Cotización</label><br>

    <label><input type="radio" name="tipos" value="Precios"> Precios</label><br>

    <label><input type="radio" name="tipos" value="Contactar"> Contactar con una persona</label><br>

    <label><input type="radio" name="tipos" value="Ubicación"> Ubicación</label><br>

  </p>

 </form>          
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="bot-inbox inbox">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                </div>

            
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="typing-field">
            <div class="input-data">
                <input id="data" type="text" placeholder="Escribe algo aquí.." >

                <button id="send-btn" >Enviar</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>

//traer valor del radio button al input text
        $("input").change(function(){

$("#data").val($("input:checked").val());

//desmarcar 
document.getElementById('send-btn').onclick = function() {
    var radio = document.querySelector('input[type=radio][name=tipos]:checked');
    radio.checked = false;
} 




    
});
      
    
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#send-btn").on("click", function() {
                $value = $("#data").val();
                $msg = '<div class="user-inbox inbox"><div class="msg-header"><p>' + $value + '</p></div></div>';
                $(".form").append($msg);
                $("#data").val('');

                // iniciar el código ajax

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'message.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 'text=' + $value,
                    success: function(result) {
                        $replay = '<div class="bot-inbox inbox"><div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></div><div class="msg-header"><p>' + result + '</p></div></div>';
                        $(".form").append($replay);
                        // cuando el chat baja, la barra de desplazamiento llega automáticamente al final
                        $(".form").scrollTop($(".form")[0].scrollHeight);
                    }
                });
            });
        });


//enviar el mensaje al presionar enter
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#data").keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.which === 13) {
            $("#send-btn").click();
        }
    });
 
    $("#send-btn").click(function() {
        
    })
});
    



    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: que tiene que ver esto con php?

Comment: Revisa la lógica y su implementación, porque está bastante regular tirando para mal. Ten en cuenta que esto `$("input").change(function(){` afecta tanto a los input radio como al input text, entonces esto que tienes dentro `$("#data").val($("input:checked").val());` se ejecuta también en el onchange del input text, haciendo que dé igual lo que escribas.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP Muchas gracias por tu sugerencia! me sirvió mucho a comprenderlo y reemplacé lo que me dijiste por esta condición: `$(document).on('change','input[type="radio"]' ,function(e) {
    if(this.id=="cotiza") {
        if(this.checked) $('#data').val(this.value);
        else $('#data').val("");` y lo hice con los cuatro input radio y ahora funciona tal como quería, de nuevo gracias, aún sigo aprendiendo de esto